Could not complete your request because a SOFn, DQT, or DHT JPEG marker is missing before a JPEG SOS marker
I am trying to understand the old Whatsapp downloaded jpeg not opening in Photoshop message, "Could not complete your request because a SOFn, DQT, or DHT JPEG marker is missing before a JPEG SOS marker".

There is WhatsAppJpegRepair app but it uses jpeg.encode
I do not know if it is lossless because I did not manage to run it neither on Mac El Capitan nor Windows 7.
I found this https://fhtr.org/DataStream.js/jpeg.html website that shows jpeg header. I loaded the "faulty" jpeg and it has a simple straightforward header only consisting of SOFn, DQT, and DHT JPEG markers before a JPEG SOS marker.
{
    "start": 65496,
    "markers": [
        {
            "tag": 65504,
            "tagName": "APP0",
            "length": 16,
            "data": {
                "jfif": "JFIF",
                "data": {
                    "majorVersion": 1,
                    "minorVersion": 1,
                    "units": 0,
                    "xDensity": 1,
                    "yDensity": 1,
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "width": 0,
                        "height": 0,
                        "data": {}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "tag": 65499,
            "tagName": "DQT",
            "length": 132,
            "data": 130
        },
        {
            "tag": 65474,
            "tagName": "SOF2",
            "length": 17,
            "data": 15
        },
        {
            "tag": 65476,
            "tagName": "DHT",
            "length": 49,
            "data": 47
        },
        {
            "tag": 65498,
            "tagName": "SOS",
            "length": 12,
            "data": {
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "huffmanTable": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "huffmanTable": 16
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "huffmanTable": 16
                    }
                ],
                "imageData": 110468
            }
        }
    ],
    "end": 65497
}

If I look at the same file resaved in Preview (need to adjust the quality slider or it just leaves it as is), it adds whole bunch of tags – couple of duplicates, and an Exif section.
{
    "start": 65496,
    "markers": [
        {
            "tag": 65504,
            "tagName": "APP0",
            "length": 16,
            "data": {
                "jfif": "JFIF",
                "data": {
                    "majorVersion": 1,
                    "minorVersion": 1,
                    "units": 0,
                    "xDensity": 72,
                    "yDensity": 72,
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "width": 0,
                        "height": 0,
                        "data": {}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "tag": 65505,
            "tagName": "APP1",
            "length": 88,
            "data": {
                "exif": "Exif\u0000\u0000",
                "data": {
                    "endianness": "MM",
                    "magic": 42,
                    "firstOff": 8,
                    "entries": [
                        {
                            "tag": 274,
                            "type": 3,
                            "count": 1,
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "tag": 34665,
                            "type": 4,
                            "count": 1,
                            "value": "38"
                        }
                    ],
                    "dirOffsets": []
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "tag": 65517,
            "tagName": "APP13",
            "length": 56,
            "data": "Photoshop 3.0\u00008BIM\u0004\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u00008BIM\u0004%\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0010Ô\u001dÙ\u0000²\u0004é\tìøB~"
        },
        {
            "tag": 65474,
            "tagName": "SOF2",
            "length": 17,
            "data": 15
        },
        {
            "tag": 65476,
            "tagName": "DHT",
            "length": 31,
            "data": 29
        },
        {
            "tag": 65476,
            "tagName": "DHT",
            "length": 195,
            "data": 193
        },
        {
            "tag": 65476,
            "tagName": "DHT",
            "length": 31,
            "data": 29
        },
        {
            "tag": 65476,
            "tagName": "DHT",
            "length": 195,
            "data": 193
        },
        {
            "tag": 65499,
            "tagName": "DQT",
            "length": 67,
            "data": 65
        },
        {
            "tag": 65499,
            "tagName": "DQT",
            "length": 67,
            "data": 65
        },
        {
            "tag": 65498,
            "tagName": "SOS",
            "length": 12,
            "data": {
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "huffmanTable": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "huffmanTable": 17
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "huffmanTable": 17
                    }
                ],
                "imageData": 675297
            }
        }
    ],
    "end": 65497
}

What I further notice is that it also becomes progressive. Is it perhaps something that Photoshop was missing in the original file?
Can anybody shed some light on it?

Ask someone to run the WhatsApp fix program on a device usable in 2024 then. Don't know why people are still stuck on such old and unsupported systems.
